# SQLite3 Query - Incorrect output

Tags: sqlite

I am running 1 specific query over my database in SQLite3 and it is giving me the wrong output.

The question that I posed for myself is to:

**Find the total number of itemID's of auctions with the highest current price.**

The answer is 1,046,871,451, however I get 300k more than that.

There are my tables/relations:

- Item (ItemID, Name, Currently, Buy_Price, First_Bid, Number_of_Bids,
  Started, Ends, UserID, Description)
- User (UserID, Rating, Location, Country)
- Category (ItemID, Category)
- Bid (ItemID, UserID, Time, Amount)

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT ItemID
FROM Item
WHERE Currently
IN (SELECT MAX(Currently) FROM Item);
```

I am really at a lost and would like any input about my query. Many thanks in advance.

**Edit Note**: Currently = the current price of the item.

**Edit 2**: 2nd attempt

```
SELECT ItemID
FROM Item
WHERE Currently 
IN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Currently) FROM Item GROUP BY ItemID);
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, I tried to think about it by going through the attributes, but Ends only contains the time in which the auctions ends.

Comment: I have checked the other columns myself as well, Buy_Price might be viable, but I get the wrong output for that also.

Comment: How do you now that 1046871451 is the correct answer?

Comment: I think the problem is that Currently probably matches to more than one thing, because currently will match all highest bids and those can be non unique.

Comment: try adding `Group by ItemID`

Comment: 1046871451 is the correct answer since the test database is manage by another person. 

I have made another attempt but I got a wrong output still. I have edited it above.